# Apache Redirect after a RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect to a "mobile" version of the site, done by the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ipad|iphone|ipod" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mobile.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?m=t [L,R=302,co=mobile:true:.domain.com]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ipad|iphone|ipod" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}   ^.*mobile=true.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=t(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?m=t [L,R=302,co=mobile:true:.domain.com,QSA]
```

Now this works for the root.
But since the site depends heavily on rewrites, if I modify

```
RewriteRule ^$ /?m=t [L,R=302,co=mobile:true:.domain.com,QSA]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?m=t [L,R=302,co=mobile:true:.domain.com,QSA]
```

It'll give me the correct redirect, but without any previous rewrites.

so if I have say a rewrite previously that was

```
RewriteRule ^product/shimano$ /index.php?product_cat=shimano [L]
```

The modified line will give me /index.php?m=t&product_cat=shimano instead of /product/shimano?m=t

What am I missing? I've been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try redirecting first, then rewriting. That is, put these mobile check rules in front of the rewrites.

That way, if it's mobile, and m=t isn't there, it will do the 302 redirect with m=t added. That will then come through again, skip these rules (since m=t is there), and continue on wiht the normal rewrites.

I'm not entirely sure about the first set of rules above. They might also need that line from the second set, that does the querystring check for m=t, to avoid an infinite loop. Basically, if it already has m=t, then it doesn't do it again.